# How does Apache 2.2 know about my server's second IP, and how can I hide it?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, httpd.conf

My server has two IP addresses, and I want two Apache services listening to each one separately.  The DNS has this:

1. a CNAME alias pointing 'intranet' to servername
2. a Host (A) record pointing servername to IP 1
3. a Host (A) record pointing 'dev' to IP 2

I have an Apache service running with `Listen intranet:80`, but it has decided to listen on IP 1 *and* IP 2, so I can't start the second service.  How did it even get to IP 2 when the path through DNS should just lead it to IP 1?  My guess is that it resolves to 127.0.0.1 and then binds to all IPs available.  If that's the case, will `Listen IP1:80` actually force it not to use IP 2, or will the same logic apply and it will use all available IPs?  If the latter, *is* there actually a way to configure Apache to only listen on IP 1?  (I only ask rather than experiment, because this is a live system and I don't want to cause more downtime than I need to.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Listen IP1:80` and it will only bind to that IP.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html

> When Apache starts, it binds to some port and address on the local
>   machine and waits for incoming requests. By default, it listens to all
>   addresses on the machine. However, it may need to be told to listen on
>   specific ports, or only on selected addresses, or a combination of
>   both.

Comment: Now that I go and do it, I realize that other services I have which have versioned httpd.conf files also use Listen with a name.  I don't suppose there's a way to do it without touching the other httpd.confs at the moment, like some Windows filter?

Comment: What sort of other programs?

Comment: Like other Apache services I didn't mention originally.

Comment: On the same machine, or is it on different servers?

Comment: Hey, I'm off for the night, I'll try and look in on this tomorrow!